# Proxy_pass from foo.website.com to localhost:xxxx using nginx on docker - not localhost on physical machine

Tags: nginx, localhost, docker

I am trying to get foo.website.com to show what's on localhost:8181, and bar.website.com to show localhost:3000. However, I want it to show the localhost from a docker box (where :8181 and :3000 show what I want), not the localhost on my physical machine(where they are blank - not in use.) I'm using nginx to do this, and the nginx config is in my docker file.

Gaphite is running on localhost:3000 and graph-explorer (better looking / tag supporting graphite front end) is on localhost:8181 - both work as expected when I put the url directly into my browser. Graphite's manage.py is running on localhost:8080, which is why graph-explorer is on :8181.

This is my first post here, and I'm new to docker/nginx and networking in general, so if I'm missing info / being unclear, I'd be happy to correct...

```
nginx settings:
server {
    listen 80;
    root /opt/graphite/webapp/content;
    index index.html;

    location / {
      # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
      try_files \$uri @app;
    }

    # The location is where I'm trying to go from
    location foo.website.com {
      # This is the port graph-explorer is running on
      proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8181;
    }

    location @app {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^()(.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
    }


    server_name website.com;
}
```

In my hosts file (both in the docker machine and in the virtual box docker runs in - not sure if I should have both?)

```
127.0.0.1 foo.website.com
127.0.0.1 bar.website.com
```

It's worth noting that this is mostly cobbled together from bits I find online, so if something is fishy, the answer probably is "Matthew is an idiot."

Many thanks :)
M

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you want:

foo.website.com proxy pass to localhost:8181
bar.website.com proxy pass to localhost:3000

Try this:

```
server {  
    listen 80;
    server_name foo.website.com;

    # foo.website.com proxy pass to localhost:8181

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8181;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name bar.website.com;

    # bar.website.com proxy pass to localhost:3000

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, reply much appreciated :) Secondly, I'm getting an error from nginx:
    Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "proxy_set_header"
Not sure why - the examples I see on the net all seem to use the same syntax you did.

Comment: I have no idea. It works for me with nginx 1.4.x. :)

Comment: Right, so it turns out the cat command wasn't working as I expected it to... my bad.
Unfortunately, the issue hasn't changed: it still uses the localhost from my physical machine, not the docker box. Unfortunately, this means that the wrong ports are still being forwarded. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: The $ characters aren't getting properly escaped. Thus they disappear. Add a \ before the $ character.